# Grails sessionFactory equivalent of Domain.withNewSession and withTransaction

Tags: grails

I'd like to be able to use withNewSession and withTransaction without having to refer to an arbitrary domain class.

Where in the grails source code does it metaprogram the withNewSession and withTransaction methods? I'd like to copy the implementation onto a generic class.

My blind guess would be implementing using sessionFactory
      //psuedo code
      class SessionManager{
          public withNewSession(Closure cl){
              cl.call(sessionFactory.openSession())
         }
      }

Less sure how I'd implement withTransaction
(I ran a search in the github repo but didn't see anything relevant)

Comment: I believe you are looking for https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5/src/main/groovy/org/grails/orm/hibernate/GrailsSessionContext.java

Comment: @ylima I don't think the methods are implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

> Where in the grails source code does it metaprogram the withNewSession
>   and withTransaction methods?

It depends on which version of GORM and which GORM implementation.  Take a look at the following:

`withNewSession`:

https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/blob/5a043739e5f7d4853535dfe8662483194d0c6c73/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5/src/main/groovy/org/grails/orm/hibernate/AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy#L80

`withSession`:

https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/blob/5a043739e5f7d4853535dfe8662483194d0c6c73/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5/src/main/groovy/org/grails/orm/hibernate/AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy#L86

I hope that helps.